# PictureBox not sizing properly

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I created a PictureBox and load an image into it, and I wanted the pictures to have a maximum size (let's say 250px). Here is the code I'm using at that moment

```
PictureBox cellPictureBox = new PictureBox();
                            cellPictureBox.AutoSize = false;
                            cellPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                            cellPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                            cellPictureBox.Image = Base64ToImage(data.ToString().Trim());

                            cellPictureBox.Width = 250;
                            cellPictureBox.Height = 250;
```

When I load the first image, it's quite large. When I load a second image, it's automatically scaled down to be very tiny, and the newly loaded image takesthe large size the first image had. This trend continues as I add more rows to my data.[image]

What can I do to help manage the sizing of my images? Making a custom control I've been told is useful, but I don't see what is happening that I have wrong.

Comment: Just set a maxwidth and height on your picturebox.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more?

Comment: `cellPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` This doesn't go well with `cellPictureBox.Width = 250; cellPictureBox.Height = 250;`

Comment: @HNLearner I essentially want to set a maximum size (and if possible a minimum too) of the PictureBoxes that are being placed in this column so that the images aren't sizing between incredibly massive and ridiculously small

Comment: @Trey I tried doing cellPictureBox.MaximumSize.Width or Height and even though it has a { get; set; } property, tells me I cannot set this Control property

Comment: @taw Good eye! Damned I feel stupid.  You nailed it :-)

Comment: I thought @taw had a good suggestion, but it didn't change the behavior when I changed that bit

Comment: Well, show us the current state of the code, then. If you delete the docking the size should stay fixed and the image should always fill at least one side. - Also: You speak about 'rows'; what does that mean? Is there one or more PictureBoxes? Is it/are they contained in some control? You need to be clearer about what you have..

Comment: You guys can abandon this post - I was fighting two problems at once I didn't realize, and it would be rather drawn out to try and re-edit everything. Flagged to have a moderator remove it. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

To set maximum and minimum sizes, have a look at the following:

```
PictureBox cellPictureBox = new PictureBox();
cellPictureBox.AutoSize = false;
cellPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
cellPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
cellPictureBox.Image = Base64ToImage(data.ToString().Trim());

cellPictureBox.MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100); // or whatever size you want.
cellPictureBox.MaximumSize = new Size(250, 250);
```

If you only want to set a limit on one dimension, for example, the width, but the height is allowed to be anything, then use int.MaxValue:

```
cellPictureBox.MaximumSize = new Size(250, int.MaxValue);
```